# Matplotlib pdf backend can not save pdf with usetex

Tags: python, matplotlib, savefig

While running the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.savefig("plot.pdf")
```

I get the very long error, finally saying `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''`. The code was working fine some time ago. However, when using the `backend="pgf"` backend, the figure is saved as desired. What is the reason for this?

I cleared `matplotlib` config and cache before.

```
>>>!python -V
Python 3.9.10
>>>print(matplotlib.__version__)
3.5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Alt. way: try to save as .svg, then convert online to .pdf.

I recommend [this](https://fixthephoto.com/online-svg-editor.html) site.